# Difference between android SDK versions

Tags: android, sdk, version

I want to know what is the difference between using Android x.x version and Android Google Api x.x ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Google API includes Google Maps, some demo and documentation about it, and also USB Open Accessories. More details [here](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Android Google Api x.x has Google Maps enabled...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use google API when your app is related with any location finding section.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but i want to know why they d'ont use one version including everything,
extra features d'ont hurt :)

Comment: IF you feel that answer has helped you .. please mark as correct.. that other can take help from this, Thanks